# Gather divs and perform CSS on them: HTMLCollection vs Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Wondering how I can make this work properly:

```
var ArrayTest = [1,2,3,4,"test"];
var ArrayTest2 = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');
ArrayTest2.forEach( function(){
    this.style.display = 'none'; 
});
```

So ArrayTest comes back as an `Array`, but ArrayTest2 comes back as an `HTMLCollection` and `forEach` throws an "undefined" type error.

How can I collect an array of elements that all have the same classname and then perform the same CSS on each one?

Comment: That would be my next step, I looked at MDN doc on HTMLCollection, it didn't list any proto functions so I figured I'd ask, if for-loop is best solutions then I'll do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do this a slightly different way, by adding a CSS class, and probably by using jQuery to make your life easier:

```
$(".mydiv").addClass("no-display");
```

then in your CSS

```
.no-display {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to assign the specific inline attribute then you could use:

```
$(".mydiv").css("display", "none");
```

**edit**

Ok so for a pure JavaScript approach

```
for (var i = 0; i < ArrayTest2.length; i++) {
   ArrayTest2[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: No jQuery please, I understand it's easier and wouldn't ask if I wanted to use it. Looking for Pure JS solution.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: You hadn't mentioned pure JavaScript although I appreciate there was no jQuery tag. It's difficult to gauge if people know what jQuery is with the variety of knowledge on the site. Anyway, I've added a pure JavaScript solution

Comment: Thanks for the for-loop, I try not to ask such trivial questions, was hoping I was missing some proto function like `forEach`.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: No problem - I guess a quick clarification in future will just help get a quicker more concise answer. I'm sure knowing about prototype functions you're way ahead than a vast majority of users on this site - something difficult to gauge from the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to be more explicit next time around, thanks for the compliment, I guess I'm ahead in some areas but not others (should have just used for-loop on my own rather than take it to the net), such is the world of code XD

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the HTMLCollection to an array by calling `Array.prototype.slice`

**Example**

```
var ArrayTest2 = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');

ArrayTest2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(ArrayTest2);

ArrayTest2.forEach( function(element){
    element.style.display = 'none'; 
});
```

**Explanation**

Calling `Array#slice` converts the collection to an array, giving you access to `Array#forEach`

With that access you can then loop through each element and easily set the display style.

---

**Example #2**

Using a similar method you can just call `Array.prototype.forEach` and bypass the slice part entirely.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv'), function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ArrayTest2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv')];
```

you could use ES6 spread operator to turn Array-like object to an actual array. It's much cleaner. (just you need to use Babel or some other compilers).